# SMTP and Unicode/UTF-8 characters...? How do I send them? base64 everything?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, smtp

Using SMTP, how do you send Unicode/UTF-8 e-mails?

Am I expected to base64 encode the UTF-8 body and specify that in the MIME header or...? How about the headers?

I'm sure there's a standard somewhere the describes this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).