# Special characters and table border in differents mails client

Tags: xml, xhtml, outlook, xslt-2.0, roundcube

I have a program who send XML mail to the client but the style of the mail is different, it depends of the mail client.
In Gmail, the special characters are good but there is no table border.
In Outlook and roundcube, the special characters are chinese characters or question mark and there is the table border.

What can I do the have the same result everywhere: special characters and table border?

Here is the code and the page where I define the css and another page that uses it: http://pastebin.com/QU7pWNMJ

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does XSLT actually work in email clients? I'm surprised. Anyway, have you tried outputting a `<meta>` element for the encoding in addition to the XML declaration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMTP and Unicode/UTF-8 characters...? How do I send them? base64 everything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562600/smtp-and-unicode-utf-8-characters-how-do-i-send-them-base64-everything)